# Grid {field:total rows} is not returning correct value

Tags: 2.7.0, grid

I have a field(let's call it `foo`) with the Grid Fieldtype.

I have conditional to check if `foo` is greater than 0 or not

Now here is the problem. It seems to me that when I only have 1 row in `foo`, `{foo:total_rows}` returns nothing.

I tried adding another row. This time `{foo:total_rows}` returns 2. It is the same thing with 3, 4, etc. Basically anything greater than 1.

This shouldn't be the case. If there is only 1 row, it should return 1.

I would to point out that the `foo` field is in a Channel with multiple Grid fieldtypes. It also has a relationship fieldtype for one of its columns.

I have another Grid field in that channel but without a realationship fieldtype for one of its columns. It is working correctly.

Any idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE**:

Tried out this code

```
<h3>field_total_rows {foo:field_total_rows}</h3>
<h3>total_rows {foo:total_rows}</h3>

{foo}
    <h3>loop field_total_rows {foo:field_total_rows}</h3>
    <h3>loop total_rows {foo:total_rows}</h3>
{/foo}
```

Output when the field contains only 1 row

```
field_total_rows
total_rows
loop field_total_rows 1
loop total_rows 1
```

Output when the field contains 2 rows

```
field_total_rows
total_rows 2
loop field_total_rows 2
loop total_rows 2
loop field_total_rows 2
loop total_rows 2
```

- Does this mean that the `total_rows` and `field_total_rows` can only be accessed inside the loop?
- Why does the total rows variable only appear if it is greater than 1?

Comment: This may be a bug re: no count when there's only one row, but `field_total_rows` is not available in the shortcut syntax ([see docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/grid.html#modifiers)) - which makes sense, because it only exists to ignore any parameters you've set on the tag pair.

Comment: I have already submitted this as a bug to the EE bugtracker. Hopefully someone will address this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If your conditional is checking if it is > 0 this would work fine as a replacement:

```
{if foo:total_rows != ""}
     You have more than 1 row.
{if:else}
     You have 1 row.
{/if}
```